# установка с флешки centos 6.5

Tags: centos

При установке с флешки в графическом режиме Сentos 6.5 (версия desctop) с начала все идет нормально система успешно ставится и для завершения надо перезагрузиться, но после перезагрузки установка не продолжается , а на черном экране висит сообщение:

minimal bash-like line editing is supported
for the first word,TAB lists possible command completions
anywhere else TAB lists the possible completions of a device\filename

Подскажите пожалуйста как тут закончить установку ? 
Ставлю линукс только 2-й раз, знаний мало.
Может ли это быть от того что с флещкой что-то не так ?
При нажатии на TAB (как я поняла тут должна быть справка) вижу просто текст описывающий процесс установки (скорее всего) а не список команд которые можно применить.
Флешка была мультизагрузочная, созданная в виндовс 7 с пом.прог. WinSetupFromUSB-1-4. Первый раз на ноутбук установила с нее Сentos 6.5 - все установилось, а дома на компьютере при установке была не очень внимательна, не убрала галочку и получилось что загрузчик установился на флешке, а Сentos 6.5 на HDD :-))) .Тут Centos установился, но не дело так загружаться, я решила все переделать, с флешки уже ничего нельзя было установить, заново ее создала в WinSetupFromUSB на этом же носителе, заново начала ставить систему и получила после перезагрузки черный экран с вышеупомянутым сообщением ! (((

Подскажите в чем может быть проблема? Может образ плохо записался ? Может создать новую загр. флешку на др. носителе ? CD-DVD в компе нет. Создавать флешку могу пока только в виндовс.

Comment: я правильно понял, что компьютер с рабочим дистрибутивом *centos* у вас уже есть? тогда надёжнее будет скопировать образ на флэшку на этом компьютере.

Comment: Да, на работе на ноутбуке стоит . Вы рекомендуете создать загрузочную флешку на нем ? Или образ с ноута перенести на компьютер (несмотря на разное железо) ?      Хотелось бы конечно понять почему выскакивает черный экран после перезагрузки, что не так делается ? Или все в порядке и можно продолжить установку, только как ???

Comment: судя по тексту, который вы процитировали, *grub* всё-таки установился на винчестер. а вот установилась ли на винчестер операционная система — большой вопрос. по крайней мере *grub* её не находит там, где задано в его конфигурации. проще всего, по-моему, произвести вторую попытку установки.

Comment: *Вы рекомендуете создать загрузочную флешку на нем ? Или образ с ноута перенести на компьютер?* — загрузочный образ (iso-файл) у вас уже есть — вы его скачали. этот образ надо «один-к-одному» скопировать на флэшку — не внутрь файловой системы, созданной на флэшке, а начиная с самого первого сектора. как такое сделать под *ms/windows* (и возможно ли вообще) — я затрудняюсь подсказать — мало знаком. а в *gnu/linux* это делается элементарной командой `cp файл.iso /dev/устройство`.

Answer (score 1):

как создать установочную «флэшку» из скачанного образа в операционной системе *gnu/linux* на примере установочного образа *centos 7*:

1. для начала скачаем установочный образ с ближайшего и наиболее быстрого «зеркала». на территории России (для всех популярных дистрибутивов) это, конечно, http://mirror.yandex.ru

   заходим в [centos](http://mirror.yandex.ru/centos/) → версия [7](http://mirror.yandex.ru/centos/7/) → каталог с образами [isos](http://mirror.yandex.ru/centos/7/isos/) → архитектура [x86_64](http://mirror.yandex.ru/centos/7/isos/x86_64/) (эта версия centos выходит только для одной архитектуры).

   и скачиваем какой-нибудь *live-образ* (впоследствии, записанный на «флэшку», он может пригодиться — с «флэшки» будет загружаться почти полноценная система с графикой и всем прочим), например, `CentOS-7-x86_64-LiveGNOME-1503.iso` или `CentOS-7-x86_64-LiveKDE-1503.iso` (размер у файлов — около одного гигабайта).
2. теперь, скорее всего, придётся немного «повоевать» с «услужливой» автоматикой: наверняка после того, как вы подключите «флэшку», файловые системы с её разделов будут «автомагически» примонтированы. а для того, чтобы скопировать на неё файл с образом, надо сначала все эти файловые системы отмонтировать. примерный алгоритм:

   1. **до** подключения «флэшки» посмотрите с помощью программы `df` текущий список примонтированных файловых систем. просто запомните, сколько строк выводится (или примерное содержимое последней строки) — новые строки (после подключения устройства) будут появляться в конце этого списка. ориентировочный вывод программы:

      ```
      $ df
      ...
      /dev/sda1  233191  67320  153430  31% /boot
      ```
   2. спустя несколько секунд после подключения «флэшки» к списку добавится строка такого, например, вида:

      ```
      /dev/sdb1 3936740  4 3936736 1% /media/user/blabla
      ```

      здесь `/dev/sdb1` — это раздел на флэшке, который и надо отмонтировать:

      ```
      $ umount /dev/sdb1
      ```

      а `/dev/sdb` (без цифр в конце, соответствующих номерам разделов) — путь к самому блочному устройству, на которое и надо будет производить запись образа. запомните этот путь.
3. если на предыдущем шаге ничего не примонтировалось и вы до сих не знаете имени блочного устройство, под которым «флэшка» подключилась, выполните команду:

   ```
   $ dmesg | tail
   ...
   [1056151.040556] scsi 15:0:0:0: Direct-Access     JetFlash Transcend 16GB   1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
   [1056151.040848] sd 15:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
   [1056151.041737] sd 15:0:0:0: [sdb] 30867456 512-byte logical blocks: (15.8 GB/1 4.7 GiB)
   [1056151.042036] sd 15:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
   [1056151.042039] sd 15:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
   [1056151.042420] sd 15:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: disabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
   [1056151.046188]  sdb: sdb1
   [1056151.048090] sd 15:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
   ```

   из приведённого ориентировочного вывода видно, что подключилось блочное устройство `sdb`, а путь к нему будет звучать как: `/dev/sdb`.
4. теперь, обладая информацией о пути к блочному устройству (в нашем примере — `/dev/sdb`), и убедившись, что никаких файловых систем с «флэшки» не примонтировано, можно копировать образ:

   ```
   $ sudo cp путь.к.сохранённому.файлу.iso /dev/sdb
   ```

   по окончании копирования на всякий случай сбросьте дисковые кэши:

   ```
   $ sync
   ```

   всё, «флэшку» можно отключать и использовать в качестве загрузочного устройства.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ !  Систему пробовала ставить заново уже много раз и всегда возвращаюсь к этому экрану ((( , пробовала и 6.5 и 6.6 результат одинаковый. Делаю установку по инструкции (отксерокопировала) со скриншотами . Попробовала 6.3 - так после начала установки флешка переставала инициализироваться ((( Завтра на работе попробую проверить флешку на другой машине . Наверно все же что-то с ней не в порядке (или матернка у меня такая - gigabit ga-g33 ?), Попробую создать на ноуте где Сentos новый носитель как вы рекомендуете. Отпишусь. Еще раз большое спасибо !

Comment: я рекомендую ставить наиболее новую версию дистрибутива. на текущий момент самая новая версия дистрибутива *centos* — это 7. если процессор поддерживает 64-битные инструкции — используйте именно её. и только если не поддерживает — выберите образ предыдущей, 6-й ветки. последняя версия в этой ветке на текущий момент — 6.7. определить, поддерживаются ли 64-битные инструкции достаточно просто: если не поддерживаются, то установка с 64-битного установочного образа даже не начнётся.

Comment: проверить целостность содержимого на установочном носителе можно прямо из меню загрузки, выбрав соответствующий пункт (обычно он присутствует).

Comment: Короче - я поставила систему по сетке  чтоб не мучиться, все получилось ! Александр, благодарю вас за помощь !