# Запись образа на sd-карту

Tags: ubuntu

Пытаюсь установить raspbian на sd.

```
sudo dd bs=4M if=2018-10-09-raspbian-stretch.img of=/dev/sdb1 conv=fsync
```

выдает ошибку

`dd: error writing '/dev/sdb1': Operation not permitted`

никак не могу найти в чем проблема

Comment: 1, sd-карты вроде бы по другому именуются. посмотрите `$ ls /sys/block` до и после подключения карты. 2. если всё-таки действительно `sdb`, то блочное устройство так и надо адресовать: `/dev/sdb`. а `/dev/sdb1` — это **первый раздел** на блочном устройстве `sdb`. вам же не внутрь раздела надо файл записать, а прямиком на блочное устройство. 3. раздел(ы) после подключения у-ва могли примонтироваться услужливым ии. надо отмонтировать прежде чем писать. 4. и не стоит усложнять себе жизнь — программа *cp* отлично справляется с копированием файлов: `$ sudo cp файл.с.образом /dev/sdb`

Comment: в помощь: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/706508/178576), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/468958/178576), [3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/435073/178576), [4](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/441725/178576) и т.д. и т.п.